# Pass locale from Spring web App to KeyCloak and back

Tags: locale, keycloak

I have a multilingual spring boot web app which integrates with Keycloak (openId). For the Keycloak integration I´m using the keycloak-spring-security-adapter. The Locale state in my application is managed by the LocaleContextHolder. How can I pass my locale to Keycloak login page? I´ve found out there is a url parameter 'kc_locale', but I have no idea how to pass it, if I don´t want to override a lot of classes from Keycloak.

Is there an easy way to pass the locale to Keycloak login/Keycloak adapter?

Answer (score 1):

While I know you're asking about Spring/Java, I wanted to give you something that may help

The OpenID Connect spec (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) has a parameter *ui_locales* which may be helpful

> ui_locales
>       OPTIONAL. End-User's preferred languages and scripts for the user interface, represented as a space-separated list of BCP47 [RFC5646]
>   language tag values, ordered by preference. For instance, the value
>   "fr-CA fr en" represents a preference for French as spoken in Canada,
>   then French (without a region designation), followed by English
>   (without a region designation). An error SHOULD NOT result if some or
>   all of the requested locales are not supported by the OpenID Provider.

You can pass this parameter to your OpenID Connect request, and Keycloak should honour it, according to this description: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_locale_selector

> With internationalization enabled, the locale is resolved in the
>   following priority:
>
> ```
> kc_locale query parameter
>
> KEYCLOAK_LOCALE cookie value
>
> User’s preferred locale if a user instance is available
>
> ui_locales query parameter
>
> Accept-Language request header
>
> Realm’s default language
> ```

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it does not address how to set that parameter using the 
 spring boot keycloak adapter.